# JHipster Create Entity With Custom Data Type

Tags: jhipster

Is there a way to register a custom data type with JHipster so it shows up as a selection when creating a new Entity?

yo jhipster:entity MyNewEntity

? What is the type of your field? (Use arrow keys)
❯ String 
  Integer 
  Long 
  Float 
  Double 
  BigDecimal 
  LocalDate 
(Move up and down to reveal more choices)

Answer (score 1):

No it's not currently possible and it would not be easy as user would have to tell JHipster how to serialize this type both in database (column types) and in frontend (JSON and frontend model).

Feel free to propose a feature request on github and if team accepts it, you can contribute by submitting a pull request.